# Searching for a quote or saying in Islam

Tags: quran

A professor in my religions class verbally mentioned the following quote/saying:

> *When religions divide people they get away from God*

Unfortunately, he doesn't know the origin of the quote/saying and I wasn't able to find it.

In this respect, I was wondering whether there are any Islamic quotes/sayings with the same or a similar meaning?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but I found an ayah in quran which has a similar meaning. See [49:13](http://quran.com/49/13)

**O mankind, indeed We have created you from male and female and made you peoples and tribes that you may know one another. Indeed, the most noble of you in the sight of Allah is the most righteous of you. Indeed, Allah is Knowing and Acquainted.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not (I doubt anyone is) able to rule out any saying in Islamic (or any other) culture because noone can know all the sayings of a culture. Considering the fact that a lot of sayings from all around the world are used by muslims, which don't have a thing to do with Islam it's hard to tell whether that specific quote derives from any Islamic country or not.

However I'd say that this quto can't be from Islam itself because Islam - like all the other monotheistic religions - argue that Islam (or any other religion)  is the only religion "close" to God and all the others are "away" from God.